# how to get rid of "open in terminal" choise in Thunar

Tags: menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize files context menu in Xubuntu XFCE Thunar file manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18367/how-to-customize-files-context-menu-in-xubuntu-xfce-thunar-file-manager)

I want to open a folder in a launcher menu (Home), say "downloads". I select it and then a submenu emerges with two choises: uppermost "downloads",and behind it "open in terminal". How can I get rid of that submenu and just get into "downloads"? one click-> downloads (no submenues)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Thunar, I suppose you are using xfce (or xubuntu) so this behavior is when you open thunar from the launcher panel using Directory Menu launcher. In the panel menu, you can add 2 different launchers for Thunar, one with the additional submenu you have (called Directory Menu) and the other (called Locals) without the additional submenu (the way you want). You can edit your panel and change the Directory Menu launcher to Locals launcher.

Obs: not sure of the English names of the launchers... may be something similar but not exact.

Comment: ... well using my english to understand plus a translation in greek, I can say I 've got it! Thank You! It was exactly what I meant!

Comment: lol ;) mine isn't in greek so all the steps were needed! Glad it worked.