# File/directory compare with right click in Thunar / Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, thunar

I would like to be able to compare files or directories by multiple-selecting them and then right clicking (for example, if there was a "compare" option in the context menu).

On Ubuntu with Nautilus, I would install the package *nautilus-compare*. How can I get this ability in Xubuntu? (in Thunar in Xubuntu - I don't mean by installing Nautilus)

The comparison program I use is meld, but a general answer would be most useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, Thunar makes it easy to do this. It has something called "custom actions". [An answer to this question about customizing context menus in Thunar](https://askubuntu.com/a/193769/59292) contains a tutorial of how to do this.

I added a new custom action called "Compare" by going to edit->configure custom actions. For using meld, like I wanted, I used the command *meld %f*, and in the "Appearance Conditions" tab, I chose text files and directories.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is very close, but not entirely correct.

In order to compare multiple files / directories, create a new Action with the following command:

> meld %F

Only using "meld %f" will only allow you to open one object in meld.

See attached screenshots for an example.

[Basic Action Seetings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orW9h.png)

[Action Appearance Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPXHx.png)

I would have made this a comment, but I am not yet allowed to do so.

Answer (score -1):

I'm an xubuntu user but not a Thunar user.  As you may have noticed it isn't brimming with features.  Sometimes light can be TOO light.

My solution to disliking Thunar is to use Dolphin, which is a KDE app and my favorite file manager, hands down.  Installing it pulls in a shedload of KDE dependencies but that doesn't bug me.

You could just try installing nautilus.  If doing a web search on "xfce thunar compare files" or something similar I yielded nothing I'd definitely do it.