# Right-click convert PDF to JPG?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, image-processing

Looking for an easy way for one of my employees to convert PDF files to a JPG. I can do something in CLI, but he can't. It has to either be automated (less desirable), or a right click convert thing.

The reason being so that he can download a PDF from his email, and print it on a Zebra printer in glabel.

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you accept online free and secure tool to do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally recommend using a web-based solution.  It won't be right-click, but your employee won't have to go into cli.  Just google "pdf to jpg" and you'll come up with tons of sites that will do it for you.  I hesitate to share links, since they can easily die, but several that I recognized right away and that I use from time to time are:

- [FileProInfo](https://fileproinfo.com/converter/pdf-to-jpg)
- [ilovepdf](https://www.ilovepdf.com/pdf_to_jpg)
- [smallpdf](https://smallpdf.com/pdf-to-jpg)

And I found a few other options that I'm not familiar with, but would undoubtedly do the job as well:

- [pdf2jpg](https://pdf2jpg.net/)
- [pdftoimage](http://pdftoimage.com/)

---

Advantages of web based are simple: a simple upload suffices.  The disadvantage is that if you have to convert sensitive information, you have no 100% guarantee that your information is not leaking anywhere.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @bigmillz if it answered your question, feel free to mark it as accepted to help future users.

Comment: It mostly works...the online converters don't preserve the file at a high enough resolution it turns out. I wish glabel would accept a PDF!

Comment: @bigmillz try [this one](http://pdftojpg.me/): can you get high enough?  At fixed DPI, you can get up to 600 dpi.

Comment: Oh, wait, looks like you can actually go as high as 2400.

Comment: [This one](http://convert-my-image.com/PdfToJpg) also allows you to convert to 600dpi, and is a bit more user friendly, I find.

Comment: All of these tools upload and save your PDF at their servers, So they are not secure. You can use https://convertpdf2jpg.net which convert PDF to JPG without any file upload. If you find it ok add it to your list

Answer (score 5):

A right-click solution can also be nice in that it is faster and works also if you are off line.

No desktop environment was specified in the original question, so this answer will also be generic. Several file managers allow to define custom actions, which then can be executed by right-clicking the file.

A basic script to convert a PDF to jpg can be a one liner using [one of several tools available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50170/how-to-convert-pdf-to-image?rq=1). Using imagemagicks convert for example:

```
convert input.pdf output.jpg
```

will convert input.pdf into one or multiple jpeg files, sequentually numbered in the latter case.

Then it will depend on the file browser how this command can be incorporated into a script, and what placeholders need to be given to have input.pdf automatically substituted by the actual file name. For the default filemanager of Ubuntu 18.04, a how-to about adding your own script is provided [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto). A more powerful option that is not officially supported by the nautilus developpers, is provided by [filemanager-actions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030940/nautilus-actions-in-18-04/1031746#1031746). Users of Thunar can start [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18367/how-to-customize-files-context-menu-in-xubuntu-xfce-thunar-file-manager).